# How add value to xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have 2 method. First:

```
private static void CreateXml(DataReader reader)
    {
        XmlDocument xml=new XmlDocument();

        //Create Head xml element
        var head = xml.CreateElement("Head");
        var uniqueIdentifier = xml.CreateElement("Unique_identifier");
        var uniqueIdentifierValue = reader.GetFieldValue("uniqueIdentifier ");

        var documentNumber = xml.CreateElement("Document_number");
        var documentNumberValue = reader.GetFieldValue("documentNumber ");

        List<string> nameElementsList= new List<string>();
        nameElementsList.Add(uniqueIdentifier.ToString());
        nameElementsList.Add(documentNumber.ToString());

        List<string> fieldValuesList = new List<string>();
        fieldValuesList.Add(uniqueIdentifierValue.ToString());
        fieldValuesList.Add(documentNumberValue.ToString());

        CheckValue(reader, xml, nameElementsList, fieldValuesList);
        xml.AppendChild(head);
        head.AppendChild(name.InnerText); //this error!
    }
```

in the second method, I do checks on the null and minimum value of different types:

```
private static void CheckValue(DataReader reader, XmlDocument xml, List<string> nameElementsList, List<string> fieldValuesList)
    {
        foreach (var nameElements in nameElementsList)
        {
            var name = xml.CreateElement(nameElements);
            foreach (var fieldValues in fieldValuesList)
            {
                var value = reader.GetFieldValue(fieldValues);
                if (value is DateTime && DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()) != DateTime.MinValue ||
                    value is string && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
                {
                    name.InnerText = Text.Convert(value);
                }
                if (value is decimal) { }
            }

        }

    }
```

I need to transfer the values(name.InnerText) from the second method to the first and add the value to head.AppendChild(name.InnerText). How can do that?

Comment: Append child wants a Node not a string so change From : name.InnerText To : name.InnerXml

Comment: but vs dont see name.....screen - http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_2kb.1549540188.png

Comment: You never added name to anything in CheckValue.  CreateElement creates a new Node that is not associated with anything.  You have to add the node to an object to save values.

Comment: and I need for each name to have its own value (which are found in the second method) http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/kiss_10kb.1549542444.png

Comment: It looks like you want to read the existing xml file and extract a dictionary of names and values that later get put into your new xml file.  I have in the past for many OPs taken an xml file and reformatted into a new xml file.  Usually the OPs post sample of old and new files.  There are better way of doing the your present code.

Comment: I take the values and names from the database and all that needs to be loaded into the xml file

Comment: Shouldn't the AppendChild be in the CheckValue method so every loop of the foreach a new element gets added?